# iPhone shuts down and restarts when connected to charger

Tags: iphone, charging

My iPhone 11 pro stops on occasion after connection to the charger, shuts down and restarts after a few seconds. When it is done, the sim card is ready without the need for pin code. I am not sure when the behaviour has started to appear. iOS 15.1.
What would be the cause and how can I fix it?
Thank you very much for your assistance.

Comment: It is most probably an issue with the battery. What is your current battery health?

Comment: Maximum capacity 100% with peak performance capacity. It doesn't seem very bad, does it?